# Question about rss in iPhone Web App

Tags: iphone, rss

OK, so I'm currently having a play around building an iPhone Web App, in which it displays an RSS feed.  I have got it displaying nicely and looking good, but everytime a user clicks on the title of a story, they then get taken to the main site, which I don't want as it's not mobile optimised.  The rss feed is a full rss feed, so the whole story is in the description.  I want the description, along with other html code that's neccesary for the web app, to display when the user clicks the title.  What link I direct them to is not a problem, the problem is how to get the description displaying along with the other html when they go to that link.

Is it possible to do this?  Perhaps with javascript, which I don't really know but a few pointers would be great?!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can package up the data you have and push it into a UIWebView.

Comment: Then it's not a web app.  Thanks though.